# oracle 11 placing an nvl2 function inside another nvl2 function

Tags: sql, oracle

we have individual fields for first name, last name, middle initial and prefix.  The challenge is to return "lastname, first name, middle initial. prefix." with all the commas and the decimals.

The issue I face is using nvl2 inside the initial nvl2 to place null in the field if the middle initial and/or prefix is null.

```
{nvl2(lname, lname ||', '||fname ||' '||middle_initial ||' '|| prefix     ||'.'||null, null) as player,}
```

works fine unless there is a null value in a middle initial or prefix field, in which case we end up with at least one unattended '.'

```
 {nvl2(lname, lname ||', '||fname ||' '|| middle_initial ||' '|| nvl2(prefix, prefix ||'.'||null), null) as player,}
```

returns 'invalid number of arguments'

So far I am trying to get the prefix fix in, then I figured the middle initial fix will follow the same syntax pattern.  I have tried multiple variations on the theme shown above, but have not discovered the magic potion.

Any thoughts, insights or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH names (lname, fname, middle_initial, prefix) AS (
    SELECT 'Last Name', 'First name', 'Middle initial', 'Prefix' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Last Name', 'First name',             NULL, 'Prefix' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Last Name', 'First name',             NULL,     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Last Name', 'First name', 'Middle initial',     NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    lname || ', ' || fname || NVL2(middle_initial, ', ' || middle_initial || '.', NULL) || NVL2(prefix, NVL2(middle_initial, NULL, ',') || ' ' || prefix || '.', NULL) name
FROM
    names
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  this will need to be wrapped into a view creation statement..  would we need to place this entire statement into an inner query to go with the remainder of the view creation? there are multiple fields from several tables in the statement.

Comment: I don't understand, I made the source data just to able to execute the tranformation, just use the select expression `lname || ', ' || fname || NVL2(middle_initial, ', ' || middle_initial || '.', NULL) || NVL2(prefix, NVL2(middle_initial, NULL, ',') || ' ' || prefix || '.', NULL) as player,`

Comment: Perfect.... my bad.. I was trying to make it more complex than it needs to be... your syntax returns exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select (case when lname is null then '' else lname || ' ' end) ||
        case when fname is null then '' else fname || ' ' end) ||
        case when middle_initial is null then '' else middle_initial || '. ') ||
        prefix
       ) as name
```

I prefer `coalesce()` because it is ANSI standard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This gets us real close.  Issues: this is leaving an unattended period if middle initial is null, and there is no period after any prefix....

Comment: changing the prefix line to mirror the middle initial line gets a period after prefix, the remaining issue is an untended period where  middle initial is null.